# load one drop down on selection of other in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

how can i load second dropdown on selection of first and third on second. in asp.net mvc 2

Comment: Added most the code, I hope you can work it out from my example.

Answer (score 0):

I have the dropdown trigger an ajax post that sends the selected ID selected to a controller and then return a partial view which overwrites the html for a placeholder div.

View; this sets the ActionUrl, you will also need a placeholder div (in my case called departments) for the drop down to be injected:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ActionUrl = '<%= Url.Action("RenderDepartments", "ControllerName") %>';
    </script>
    <script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Custom/DepartmentFilter.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OfficeId, Model.ListItems, "-- Please Select --", new { onchange = "GetDepartments()" })%>
    // ^^ ON CHANGE IS IMPORTANT  ^^
    <div id="departments"></div>
```

JQuery;

```
     function GetDepartments() {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: ActionUrl,
                data: { officeId: $("#OfficeId").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                        $("#departments").html(data);
                }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('XMLHttpRequest:' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    alert('textStatus:' + textStatus);
                    //alert('errorThrown:' + errorThrown);
                }

            });
     }
```

Controller Action;

```
        public ActionResult RenderDepartments(int? officeId)
    {
        if (officeId.HasValue)
        {
            var departments = new SelectList(ents.GetDepartments(officeId), "departmentID", "Name");
            var model = new DropdownListViewModel(departments);

            return PartialView("DepartmentDropdown", model);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is nullable because the user could submit "-- please select --" which will in this case return null and remove the departments dropdown.

Comment: in this code I could not get any data for "function (data)" getting resource could not found, as an error.